# Any way using pyodbc to return literal SQL

Tags: python, sql-server, python-2.7, pyodbc

Is there any way using pyodbc to return the literal sql that was passed to the database? I'm passing parameters to statements within a for loop iterating over a list of dictionaries. For example:

```
mylist = [{'name': 'john', 'key': 1}, {'name': 'jane', 'key': 2}]
sql = "update people set name = ? where key = ?"
for i in mylist:
    cursor.execute(sql, i['name'], i['key'])
```

I'd like to be able to print or store the literal sql that the script is passing to the database. If this is not possible using pyodbc, can someone recommend a different Python module that has this feature? Thanks in advance.

Comment: AFAIK there is no "literal SQL". That's sort of the point of prepared statements - saves a lot of (expensive) string processing and (de)escaping on both ends.

Comment: Maybe I'm using the wrong terminology. For the above code, what I would want for the first iteration is the string "update people set name = 'john' where key = '1'". This way I could keep a log of all the sql statements that my script executed.

Comment: @JamesNicholson But that is not what is being sent to the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not built-in but fairly simple to implement.

Similar to the other solution. but write a generic method like:

```
def executeAndLog( db_cursor, sql, *args ) :
    run_sql = sql.replace( '?', '{!r}' ).format( *args )
    try:
        db_cursor.execute( sql, *args )
        logging.info( run_sql )
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error( " ".join( run_sql, "failed with error", e ) )
```

You will probably want some indication to the caller as to whether it succeeded or not, so either return something or re-raise an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the built-in logging module:

```
import logging
import pyodbc

# setup logging level and file name
logging.basicConfig(filename='sql.log', level=logging.DEBUG)

# connection = pyodbc....
# cursor = connection...

# define parameter values and sql 
mylist = [{'name': 'john', 'key': 1}, {'name': 'jane', 'key': 2}]
sql = "update people set name = ? where key = ?"

for i in mylist:
    cursor.execute(sql, i['name'], i['key'])
    # {!r} ensures string values wrapped with single quote
    logging.debug(sql.replace('?', '{!r}').format(i['name'], i['key']))
```

You'll probably want to add some exception handling around `cursor.execute` to only log if the call is successful.

Comment: A better "solution' would use *args